# False positive for CA1801 in Release config only

Tags: c#, code-analysis

My method reads as follows.

```
public static void Debug(this Logger logger, string message)
{
    logger.Debug(() => message);
}
```

When I run code analysis with Debug config, I get no warning.

When I run code analysis with Release config, I get:

> CA1801    Review unused parameters    Parameter 'message' of 'CommonExtensions.Debug(this Logger, string)' is never used. Remove the parameter or use it in the method body.  FakeItEasy  CommonExtensions.cs 101

and

> CA1801    Review unused parameters    Parameter 'logger' of 'CommonExtensions.Debug(this Logger, string)' is never used. Remove the parameter or use it in the method body.   FakeItEasy  CommonExtensions.cs 101

This is clearly wrong. I am using both parameters in the method body. If I remove either of the parameters then the code does not compile.

Has anyone else experienced anything similar? Have I discovered a bug in code analysis?

(I am using the same ruleset under both configurations.)

---

UPDATE

The `Logger.Debug()` signature is as follows:

```
[Conditional("DEBUG")]
public abstract void Debug(Func<string> message);
```

Comment: What is the declaration for Logger.Debug()?

Comment: I tried this with `public void Debug(Func<string> f)` and it works fine for me (with all CA warnings on). This is with VS2012 Update 1, .Net 4 or .Net 4.5 builds.

Comment: @MatthewWatson thanks - you prompted me to find the answer. will update shortly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the Q update, `Logger.Debug()` has the `Conditional` attribute set and this is the cause.

Answer (score 1):

You can fix it by adding a conditional `"CODE_ANALYSIS"` attribute:

```
[Conditional("DEBUG")]
[Conditional("CODE_ANALYSIS")]
public abstract void Debug(Func<string> message);
```

(I had the [same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31944141/814206) and found [a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31944511/814206).)

Comment: Thanks! IIRC this was a problem in https://github.com/FakeItEasy/FakeItEasy but since then the entire class has been removed so the problem has gone away.