# Suppress code analysis warnings for conditional methods

Tags: c#, conditional-statements, undefined, code-analysis

Running code analysis (Visual Studio 2015) on code that calls `Conditional` methods causes warnings for unused locals (CA1804) or unused parameters (CA1801). E.g. for:

```
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        [Conditional ("NEVER_DEFINED")]
        static void Log(string message)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("Demo conditional message logging: " + message);
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string message = "Only log this when `NEVER_DEFINE` is #defined";
            Log(message);

            Method("other message");
        }

        static void Method(string messageToLog)
        {
            Log(messageToLog);
        }
    }
}
```

Code Analysis results in:

- Warning   CA1801

  Parameter 'args' of 'Program.Main(string[])' is never used. Remove the parameter or use it in the method body.

  ConsoleApplication1   …\Program.cs    14
- Warning   CA1804

  'Program.Main(string[])' declares a variable, 'message', of type 'string', which is never used or is only assigned to. Use this variable or remove it.

  ConsoleApplication1   …\Program.cs    15
- Warning   CA1801

  Parameter 'messageToLog' of 'Program.Method(string)' is never used. Remove the parameter or use it in the method body.

  ConsoleApplication1   …\Program.cs    22

I consider the warnings about `message` and `messageTolog` as false positives.  Is there a way to have the code analysis treat the conditional methods as using the parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the `CODE_ANALYSIS` conditional attribute to the called conditional method, e.g.:

```
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        [Conditional ("NEVER_DEFINED")]
        [Conditional ("CODE_ANALYSIS")]
        static void Log(string message)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("Demo conditional message logging: " + message);
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string message = "Only log this when `NEVER_DEFINE` is #defined";
            Log(message);

            Method("other message");
        }

        static void Method(string messageToLog)
        {
            Log(messageToLog);
        }
    }
}
```

Now `Log(string)` is considered using its parameters and all parameters and local variables supplied to it are considered used as well.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `[SuppressMessageAttribute]` in `System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis`.  However you would have to apply it to each method that calls the `Conditional`-method (or apply it at broader scope); e.g.:

```
[System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage ("Microsoft.Performance", "CA1804")]
static void Main(…)
{
    …
}

[System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage ("Microsoft.Performance", "CA1801")]
static void Method(…)
{
    …
}
```

Comment: There are many methods that call these conditional log methods.  I prefer a solution that does not require annotations at every method.